# installation error typo3-neos- 500 internal server error

Tags: typo3, typo3-flow, neoscms

I have downloaded typo3-neos  using php c:/xampp/Composer/bin/composer.phar create-project --dev --stability alpha typo3/neos-base-distribution TYPO3-Neos-1.0-alpha

my httpd.conf is :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName neos.demo
DocumentRoot c:/xampp/htdocs/Typo3-Neos/Web/
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
<Directory c:/xampp/htdocs/Typo3-Neos/Web/>
DirectoryIndex index.php
AllowOverride FileInfo Options=MultiViews
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and vhost is: 127.0.0.1     neos.demo

I am geting the follwing 500 Internal Server Error (a snippet)

## 1355480641: Execution of subprocess failed with exit code 1 without any further output.

(Please check your PHP error log for possible Fatal errors)

More information
TYPO3\Flow\Core\Booting\Exception\SubProcessException thrown in file
C:\xampp\htdocs\TYPO3-Neos\Packages\Framework\TYPO3.Flow\Classes\TYPO3\Flow\Core\Booting\Scripts.php in line 532.
Reference code: 201310091327354b04b0

I have divided screenshot of the complete error page into three parts (error1.png, error2.png, error3.png) as the error stack is quite long, which is attached here
[image]
[image]
[image]

How can this be solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting your System up, start NEOS with http://neos.demo/setup first.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue on my Mac machine after a successful installation. The point was that my php installation was not linked correct to the php binary, although it was set correctly in /user/bin/php and "active"

So make sure /opt/local/etc/select/php/current points to a valid php installation using the command "sudo port select php php54" (for php 5.4)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error with setup this lines in neos\Packages\Framework\TYPO3.Flow\Configuration\Settings.yaml

**TYPO3:
   Flow:
     core:
       phpBinaryPathAndFilename: 'C:/path/to/php.exe'**

**TYPO3:
   Flow:
     core:
        subRequestPhpIniPathAndFilename: '/path/to/your/php.ini'**

This error occur because typo3flow may be not find php and php.ini files in server.

for more help follow this link: http://wiki.typo3.org/Exception/Flow/1355480641